# ABP InsertMany seems very slow

Tags: abp

I'm trying to insert approx 70k+ records into an ABP SQL Server EF database. General performance of the system is fine, but bulk inserting seems VERY slow and there is minimal if any network and CPU traffic. I'm wrapping the batches in a UnitOfWork, but either way it just seems glacial for what is a very small amount of data.

I can't see any activity on my machine (Dev) or on the SQL server for much of the time and it would appear that breaking down the 71k+ inserts into batches of 1000 doesn't improve matters. Indeed, there seems to be an slowing of the inserts as the batches clock up with the first 1000 records taking around 4 seconds, even though no actual work seems to take place on the database with later batches taking 8-10 seconds to progress.
I can't find any real help about this and have wanted to use the BulkInsert functions in EF7, but they appear to be hidden away by ABP.
Help most appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: I seem to have solved this, but by using a separate tool - https://entityframework-extensions.net/ has MASSIVELY improved performance. 30x 70k inserts done in a fraction of the time of a single 70k batch.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same solution.
But I need to manually add audit information,like creatorid
And without entity change
But it faster then ABP bulk operattions

Comment: Do you mean this to be an answer according to [answer]? If so please [edit] to make that more obvious. Otherwise please delete this.